# cut function not working in dplyr, but works outside

Tags: r, dplyr

My `cut` function works just fine outside of `dplyr`, but when I insert the same `cut` function into `mutate` it throws this error:

> Error: invalid subscript type 'double'

Sample code:

```
df <- structure(list(fyear = c(1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 
1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 
1970, 1970, 1970), BEME = c(0.39713747645951, 0.548988782444936, 
0.537154930871343, 1.89357008340059, 1.66945262543448, 0.969181836638018, 
1.09989952916609, 0.858308443214104, 0.292175536881419, 0.684685677549708, 
0.338422675433708, 3.02671555788371, 0.422643864469658, 0.805317430736738, 
0.529954031556715, 0.617716486520065, 0.911576593365635, 0.4131850675139, 
1.16211278792693, 2.13177678851802), exchg = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 11L, 12L, 
19L, 11L, 11L, 11L)), .Names = c("fyear", "BEME", "exchg"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

`cut` function

```
cut(df$BEME, breaks = quantile(df[df$exchg == 11, 2]$BEME, c(0,0.3,0.7,1)), labels = FALSE)

[1] NA  2  2  3  3  2  2  2 NA  2 NA  3  1  2  1  2  2  1  2  3
```

`dplyr`

```
newdat <- df %>% 
  group_by(fyear) %>% 
  mutate(LMH = cut(BEME, breaks = quantile(df[df$exchg == 11, 2]$BEME, c(0,0.3,0.7,1)), labels = FALSE))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
newdat <- df %>% 
  group_by(fyear) %>% 
  mutate(LMH = cut(BEME, breaks = quantile(BEME[exchg == 11], c(0,0.3,0.7,1)), labels = FALSE))
```

**Update**

The dplyr docs likely explain this better than I but here are my comments.

Since "BEME" and "exch" are part of "df", they are available in in the call to "mutate", there is no need to reference the oringinal data.frame (as in "df$BEME", etc.).  Because of the call to "group_by", first in the chain, "mutate" will process the data by groups (dplyr knows how to subset "BEME" and "exch" into groups, and cut will be called for each group).  I know that there is only one group in this example but if there is more than one group, then "df$BEME" and "df$exch" (as used in the original code) will always refer to the data across all groups even when processing the subset of data by group.

For example, if you have "df" as follows, with two groups (1970 and 2000)

```
> df
   fyear      BEME exchg
   (dbl)     (dbl) (int)
1   1970 0.3971375    11
2   1970 0.5489888    11
3   1970 0.5371549    11
4   2000 1.8935701    11
5   2000 1.6694526    11
```

"df$BEME" always refers to all of the data in that column, across groups.

```
> df$BEME
[1] 0.3971375 0.5489888 0.5371549 1.8935701 1.6694526
```

So in

```
> df %>%
  group_by(fyear) %>%
  mutate(LMH = cut(BEME, breaks = quantile(BEME[exchg == 11], c(0,0.3,0.7,1)), labels = FALSE))
```

The new column "LMH" will be created based by processing the 1970 and 2000 groups separately.  Using "df$BEME" (or "df$exchg") always refers to all of the data in all groups (i.e. df$BEME has 5 rows).

As for why the original code doesn't work in the case where there is just one group, I don't know and I will defer to someone else who better understands the inner workings of dplyr.

Comment: Maybe add some explanations too for us, the simple people.

Comment: Seems like you and the Op are really on the same wavelength on the last 3 questions. Wow :P